# jQuery: Open/request Fullscreen browser on load?

Tags: jquery, html, fullscreen, window-load

I have a page with a div `#container` which I would like to have go into full screen mode (or at least request to go into full screen mode) on supported browsers.

I downloaded [this plugin](https://github.com/martinaglv/jQuery-FullScreen)

and although the example all show using a button to enter fullscreen, I'd like to do it on load.  I tried:

```
$(window).load(function() {
        if($.support.fullscreen){
            $('#container').fullScreen();
        }
    });
```

It passes the support test (Chrome 28) but nothing happens.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem, after further research, that the fullscreen API can **only** be activated via **user interaction** for security reasons. If anyone knows otherwise, please feel free to post.

Answer (score 0):

I use a trick...
        I listen for any click on the body to activate.
Eg:

```
$('body').on('click', '*', function() {
        screenfull.request();
    });
```

N.B.: It does not track buttons (e.t.c) that already have event handlers...